# Jan 2013 - Admob AND AdWhirl?

Tags: android, admob, ads, adwhirl

I have read through lots of questions but they are all outdated and I know something went on where admob stopped adwhirl using it's ads or something.

I want to know if it is possible to have my new android app have both adwhirl and admob in it at the same time?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Adwhirl has been replaced by Admob mediation.

Admob mediation is simple use. In fact it's so simple that you just need to replace your Admob Id in your AdView constructor with your Admob mediation Id.

Admob mediation gives you access to all the networks that AdWhirl did.